# "Unable to resolve host: No address associated with hostname" error faced by users with same ISP

Tags: android, networking, dns, unknown-host

I've an application on play store. Some of the users of the app are facing the error shown as in below screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xvXi.png

**Analysis**

1. It's a transient error, meaning happening to some of the users but not all. So I believe its something local to the users devices.
2. Common things between users who faces this error is, they're using the internet via same carrier(ISP).
3. When user faces the issue, I asked them to navigate to the webpage ([link](https://diamonddiary.in/)) directly which is the same domain that application tries to connect. They were not able to open the webpage as well. So it makes sense that the problem is not within the application only. It's something about DNS resolution.
4. Based on above facts, I came to believe that the ISP's root DNS server is somehow unable to resolve the DNS of my domain.
5. To support point 4, I asked multiple users who faced this issue, to connect wifi and try again. For all of them, the app works with Wifi.

**Tried solutions**

1. I've checked stack overflow & google searches for other related question/answers but didn't found anything that can help.
2. I've tried by changing Name Servers (NS Records) of my domain by switching to different provider. After switching, didn't got reports of the error for approx. 2 weeks but then again the number of error reports started increasing.

**Advice needed is**

1. does all of the above makes sense and is 4th point correct? (I'm not a DNS expert)
2. is there any way to prove point 4 somehow?
3. any possible solutions?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should consider asking this on the networking or super user stack exchange since it's more about networking than programming.  I don't think it's inapproprate for SO but you might get better answers there .

Comment: When the app isn't working and they're not on Wifi, what are they on, Cell network?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @erik258. I will ask it on suggested site. To answer your question, yes they're on cell network as shown in attached screenshot in question. Also, they're able to browse other websites without issues so no issue with their internet connectivity.